# C# var driverService to "public"

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I using Selenium.PhantomJS with C#, I want declare driver in `public partial class` so I can call it in my methods. I have this code:

```
var driverService = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
        driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
        IWebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(driverService);
```

But I can only use it for local declaration because it's `var` 
How I can change it so I can call driver from any method ?

Comment: I don't totally understand the question. But could you not create a private method that gets the driver. It will still be accessible by your other partials.

Comment: `var` is a simple placeholder for the *known* type. Do you have trouble finding out the type of `PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService()`? The documentation and your IDE should give you all the necessary information.